# Converting Http Request to Unity Web Request

Tags: c#, .net, api, unity-game-engine

Im having issues converting my working HTTP Request to a Unity Web Request. The reason for change is I want to use WebGL and I need to use Unity web Request and cant use HTTP Web request. I have tried to convert to Unity Web Request but its not working. Here is my code:

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using WBG_4;
 
public class send : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text txtResponse;
 
    private string _Response;
 
    public void Send()
    {
        string uri = WBG_Config._EndPoint + "api/WhiteBoXGaming/Post_TestAPI";
        OAuth oAuth = new OAuth();
 
        oAuth.Administrator = WBG_Config._OAuth_Admin;
        oAuth.Password = WBG_Config._OAuth_Password;
 
        StartCoroutine(Testwebrequest(uri, oAuth));
 
        txtResponse.text = _Response;
    }
 
    IEnumerator Testwebrequest(string uri, object obj)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
 
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }
 
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            _Response = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
 
        yield return _Response;
    }
}
```

The above is working code. This request works no problem. Now I'm trying to convert to Unity Web Request. Not been successful so far. I have tried the below code and it hits the API but its all NULL. I think this code snippet is close but I'm doing something wrong causing my data to always come in as NULL.

```
IEnumerator Testwebrequest(string uri, object obj)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        _Response = Convert.ToString(result);
    }

    yield return _Response;
}
```

UPDATE:
I was able to get the call working but now I need to get the data coming back into a object. Here is what I have so far:

```
IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
{
    var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    yield return request.Send();
    
    Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);

    var response = request.downloadHandler.text;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        _Response = Convert.ToString(result);
    }

    yield return _Response;



    txtResponse.text = request.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I figured it out. I hope this helps anyone else trying to do Unity Web Request:

```
 public void Send()
{
    string uri = WBG_Config._EndPoint + "api/YOUR ROUTE HERE"; 
    OAuth oAuth = new OAuth();

    oAuth.Administrator = WBG_Config._OAuth_Admin;
    oAuth.Password = WBG_Config._OAuth_Password;

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oAuth);

    StartCoroutine(Post(uri, json));
}

IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
{
    var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
    byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
    request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    yield return request.Send();
    
    Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);

    var response = request.downloadHandler.data;
    string json = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
    var _Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);

    yield return _Response;

    txtResponse.text = _Response;
}
```

}